# Why does the peak pulse current of a TVS diode decrease as the breakdown voltage increases?

Tags: tvs

[image]

From the above picture, we can see that the peak pulse current of a TVS diode decreases as the breakdown voltage increases. Why does that happen? Usually, when the voltage is high the current should also be high.

Answer (score 0):

The component has a power limit, and if you do the math and multiply the clamping voltage and current you will see that the power dissipation limit for all those components is 1500 Watts.